# Find the area between these two functions using integration

Tags: integration, area

The functions are 
$$
f(x) = \ln (x)
$$
$$
g(x) =(\ln(x))^2 
$$

Is there a simple way of finding area other than using the long method of integration by parts

Comment: did you try substituting $t = lnx$?

Comment: So what's your integral? Have you constructed it yet?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method would be to integrate with respect to y, although this still involves integration by parts:

$\displaystyle A=\int_0^1 \left(e^{\sqrt{y}}-e^y\right)dy=\int_0^1e^{\sqrt{y}}dy-\left[e^y\right]_0^1$.  $\;\;\;$Now let $u=\sqrt{y}, y=u^2, dy=2u du$ to get

$\displaystyle A=\int_0^1e^u\cdot 2u du-(e-1)=2\left[ue^u-e^u\right]_0^1-(e-1)=2(0-(-1))-(e-1)=3-e$.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is to calculate
$$\int_{a}^{b} [g(x)-f(x)] dx$$
Then this is perhaps what you are looking for
$$\int [g(x)-f(x)] dx=x \ln^2 x-3x \ln x+ 3x$$
(The arbitrary constant has been excluded.)